# What framework can help with code coverage using service virtualization for REST template classes?

Tags: java, framework, software-testing

I am working on a Spring Boot Application which uses Camel for EIP. Also there are few rest template classes and services. So I was using Mockito and JUnit to Unit test these classes. But my teammate wanted to see if I can service virtualize the REST templates (which are used by multiple components). The main theory here is to avoid writing unit tests for each rest template and code coverage this using service virtualization.

So I tried researching for any frameworks which can be used to accomplish this. I had found Hoverfly framework but this can be used to service virtualize the external URLs only. So I am eagerly looking for any framework that could help me solve the above problem.

So please let me know if there is any framework which can solve this or we can only use Mockito or JUnit for code coverage.